# How to fetch media url through api

Tags: ruby, twilio, twilio-conversations

How do I get a media instance through the REST api? I'm looking to either download the file or fetch the url for that media. I'm using Ruby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the media SID from a [message resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/api/conversation-message-resource). For example:

```rb
account_sid = ENV['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']
auth_token = ENV['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN']
@client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(account_sid, auth_token)

messages = @client.conversations
                  .conversations('CHXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
                  .messages
                  .list(order: 'desc', limit: 20)

messages.each do |message|
  puts message.sid
  message.media.each do |media|
    puts "#{media.sid}: #{media.filename} #{media.content_type}"
  end
end
```

I've not actually tried the above, the `media` objects may just be plain hashes and you would access the sid with `media['sid']` instead.

Once you have the SID, you can [fetch the media](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/api/media-resource#retrieve-a-media-resource) by constructing the following URL using the Chat service SID and the Media SID:

```
https://mcs.us1.twilio.com/v1/Services/<chat_service_sid>/Media/<Media SID>
```

For downloading files in Ruby, I like to use the [Down gem](https://github.com/janko/down). You can read about [how to use Down to download images here](https://www.twilio.com/blog/download-image-files-ruby). Briefly, here's how you would use Down and the URL above to download the image:

```rb
conversation_sid = "CHXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
media_sid = "MEXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
account_sid = ENV["TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID"]
auth_token = ENV["TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN"]

url = "https://#{account_sid}:#{auth_token}@mcs.us1.twilio.com/v1/Services/#{conversation_sid}/Media/#{media_sid}"

tempfile = Down.download(url)
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked. The only thing I had to change was the url. It should be `url = "https://#{account_sid}:#{auth_token}@mcs.us1.twilio.com/v1/Services/#{service_sid}/Media/#{media_sid}"`